# How to properly define types for a `withProps` function for React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Here's what I've got:

```
export function withProps<P,U extends Partial<P>>(component: React.ComponentType<P>, defaultProps: U): React.FunctionComponent<P & U> {
    return props => React.createElement(component, {...defaultProps, ...props});
}
```

And here's my usage attempt:

[image]

`a` shouldn't be required for `Comp2`.

I tried updating the definition to

```
React.FunctionComponent<Omit<P,keyof U>>
```

but it doesn't like that either:

[image]

I'd think the proper output props would be `Omit<P,keyof U> & U`. i.e., we remove all of the default props and then add them back in as a Partial (all optional), but I don't know how to get that to work.

Try it here: https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-monad-pzbve

Comment: Where `Omit` comes from? This should work with built in helper (typescript 3.5 currently in RC) https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30552

Comment: @AlekseyL. `Omit` is that same type, just copied into my project. Using TS 3.4.5 right now. This doesn't seem to work as-is. Here it is showing the same errors in codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-monad-pzbve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is giving the best, most comprehensive results so far

```
export function withProps<TProps extends Record<string,any>, TDefaultProps extends Partial<TProps>=Partial<TProps>>(component: React.ElementType<TProps>, defaultProps: TDefaultProps) {
    const C = (props:TProps) => React.createElement(component, {...defaultProps, ...props});
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
        C.displayName = `withProps(${getDisplayName(component)}, ...)`;
    }
    return C as React.FunctionComponent<Omit<TProps, keyof TDefaultProps> & Partial<TDefaultProps>>;
}
```

It throws errors if you try to set a default prop that doesn't exist, allows you to omit the default props, and allows you to override the default props.

Having to use `Partial<TDefaultProps>` on that final line really confused me at first because I thought I defined it as Partial already, but then I realized that it *extends* `Partial<TProps>` but when materialized, the optionalness is effectively dropped.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit tricky. To achieve a separation of the provided properties the declaration of the combined type needs to be change like this: `TProps & TDefaultProps`. This combined type needs also to by the primary parameter of `Omit`.  After the types  `TProps` and `TDefaultProps` are separated they will not have any property in common. So it is not possible to assign both values `defaultProps` and `props` to the same object. Therefore at least one `as any` will be need.

```
function withProps<TProps, TDefaultProps>
  (component: React.ComponentType<TProps & TDefaultProps>, defaultProps: TDefaultProps):
     React.FC<Omit<TProps & TDefaultProps, keyof TDefaultProps>> {
       return props => React.createElement(component, { ...defaultProps as any, ...props});
}
```

Comment: Hmm... don't think that works either: https://i.imgur.com/tNzEnNg.png Neither `a` nor `b` are assignable on the new type.

Comment: I assumed when a component is extended using withProps, only properties should be assigned that not already have been assigned via defaultProps. So `a` can not be assigned, but b should. https://imgur.com/prXXkA0

Answer (score 1):

I took the [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-monad-pzbve) you posted and made some changes:

- I changed `withProps` into a curried function, like you might see in [recompose](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/docs/API.md#defaultprops), that takes your default props and returns a higher-order component.
- `Omit` is typed slightly wrong; the second type parameter should extend `keyof any`, the way it is in [TypeScript 3.5](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-5/#the-omit-helper-type). The reason is that the post-condition for `Omit` is "the returned type will not have any of these keys", but it does not have the pre-condition that "the given type must have all of these keys". This makes `Omit` useful in a wider range of scenarios.
- The returned component needs to accept `Partial<TDefaultProps>`, not `TDefaultProps`. `TDefaultProps` has no `undefined` properties, so they are all "required". `Partial<TDefaultProps>` lets them be optional (because they are defaulted).
- You need to cast one of the object spreads to `TProps`. The reason is an [open issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26412).

Here is the [result](https://codesandbox.io/s/bitter-pond-g40f4):

```
const defaultProps = <DefaultProps extends object>(defaults: DefaultProps) => <
  Props extends Partial<DefaultProps>
>(
  Component: React.ComponentType<Props>
) => (props: Omit<Props, keyof DefaultProps> & Partial<DefaultProps>) => (
  <Component {...defaults} {...props as Props} />
);
```

Comment: Awesome! It looks like this working how I wanted now. Can finally clean up those tsc errors :p Thanks!